# Битовые операции, задача с двумя числами.

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

Задание:

> Написать программу, которая позволит
> ввести два числа типа long с
> клавиатуры, найти и вывести на дисплей
> их сумму, используя битовые операции
> сделать в ней, чтобы 20, 10, 5 и 2
> биты были равны 0, а 18, 8, 0 - 1,
> остальные сохранили свои значения и
> вывести результат.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
long num1, num2;
cin >> num1 >> num2;
long sum = num1 + num2;
cout << sum << endl;
long mask1 = (1l << 20) | (1l << 10) | (1l << 5) | (1l << 2);
sum &= ~mask1;
long mask2 = (1l << 18) | (1l << 8) | 1l;
sum |= mask2;
cout << sum << endl;
```

Comment: Спросили бы лучше у человека, что он пробовал, что не получилось. Какой иначе смысл?)

Comment: Мне кажется в данном случае легче на примере разобраться, как битовые операции работают

Comment: Неясно что означает 1l в коде. То ли маленькая L, то ли заглавная I, то ли ¦.Прошу поправить....

P.s. смотрю с телефона, скопипастить не смогу в редактоп... Лучше сразу писать максимально ясно.

Comment: geocube: и как же вы мне предлагаете это сделать?

Comment: а зачем вообще l? по-моему 1 он и в Африке 1

Comment: А вы сравните на интерес значения 1 << 32 и 1ll << 32.

Comment: Допустим. Но при 1<<31 и менее никаких переполнений не происходит.

Comment: Это почему? Я думаю до сих пор где-нибудь используются машины, где sizeof(int) == 2. Стандарт этого не запрещает. Тем более в задании явно указано, что числа типа long.